# JNI is platform depended?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I write simple "Hello World" program with Java and JNI for Linux, and if i right for using JNI you must compile shared libs for every platform (e.g. *.so for Linux, *.dll for Windows and so on) place it somewhere near your *.jar file and write a script to execute it properly (e.g. java -jar -Djava.library.path=. your_app.jar). This makes me kinda sad because i choose Java because of platform interdependency. Of course building a exact same lib with Windows and Mac is not a big deal, but at first time i think about a JNI like a silver bullet which will combine platform independence of Java  and speed of C in a single .jar file.

Maybe i assume something wrong and  there is some way to do it?

Comment: How could a native library be platform-independent? That's an oxymoron.

Comment: Often Java has the speed of C, or so close it doesn't matter.  You rarely need to use C with Java in real programs.

Comment: Dude what part of Native in JNI don't you get? It's just how things are. And if you are using c because of speed, implement the same thing in Java and see. Chances are you will only see vary small differences in speed if any thanks to modern JVMs.

Comment: Adding to Peter's point, we use JNI for native platform services not available to us through an existing Java API, and very rarely indeed, if ever, for speed.

Comment: Try java on non x86 platform, and you'll see a factor 10 slowdown compared to native c.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If you have a late Mac then you will be on an x86/x64 platform. Or are you using an older Mac with PowerPC? Nils was talking about using Java on NON-x86.

Comment: What kind of services are you talking about?

Comment: @maba You and Nils are correct. Then my point would be that all mainstream non-mobile platforms today are x86. IBM has a proprietary mainframe platform, and again has an optimized JVM for it. As for mobile platforms, Android's Java is agressively optimized for those. So still, this needs to be qualified better.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Agree that it needs to be better qualified. Just wanted to point out what he was targeting.

Comment: Native libraries are native. Not a real question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : err... Are you talking about IBM's __midrange__ portfolio by any chance? Those unix and os-400 based servers are one of the main reasons java is so strong in the server-market compared to .net. They're not mainframes at all.

Comment: @Thihara: I don't know if it's still true these days, but there was a time when sending/receiving ICMP messages (ping and friends) directly from java was impossible without JNI.

Comment: @GergelySzilagyi Among other things I had the z/OS in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Java is *mostly* platform independent, JNI being the **BIG** exception...

Comment: And different releases of the JVM being the other. :-)

Comment: @BoPersson : not to mention the horrors one must face when using java on os x :)

Answer (score 2):

JNI = Java **Native** Interface. Native = platform dependent. JNI is optional and *very specialized* part of Java, you are not forced to use it for any of your Java coding. JNI is meant to be used for isolated tasks which absolutely cannot be done in JVM. Not for speed reasons, but for accessing native (OS level) resources/interfaces, or 3rd party native (non-JVM) monolithic libraries. Using JNI for a "better speed" and actually expecting the difference to be significant, suggests that you should perhaps use different tools altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You really have to provide a different version of the native library for every platform you're targeting. So, yes, in a way you're loosing platform portability when using JNI.

While I do not know your exact problem, I would evaluate whether native code is really important for performance reasons. In my opinion, Java is not that slow as discussed sometimes.